# Roots of a function with natural logarithm giving odd results.

Tags: logarithms, roots

Suppose $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x^2-9}{\ln(x-3)}$.

The roots of this function would occur when $x^2 - 9 = 0$, i.e. $x = \pm 3$. Clearly, $x = -3$ is not a root, since $\ln(-6)$ is undefined. However, Wolfram-Alpha states that $x = 3$ is a root, but $\ln(3-3) = 
\ln 0$ which is also undefined. How can $x = 3$ be claimed as a root then?

Comment: $\ln(0^+) = - \infty$.

Comment: $3$ is not in the domain of $f$, so cannot be a root. Maybe Wolfram-Alpha found that over $\mathbb{C}$, $f$ has roots very close to $3$.

Comment: WA is high again...not its first bug, and most probably not its last.

Answer (score 3):

since we have $x>3$ the function has no real root

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that we are working with the real logarithm, and not the complex logarithm, then $f$ is defined on the interval $(3,\infty)$, i.e. $f : (3,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$.  As you point out, there are no roots in that domain.  In a pre-calculus-style class (or any class where the domain of a function is assumed to be real), this would be the correct answer.

However, we *might* try to extended the function continuously to $3$.  Since
$$ \lim_{x\to 3^{+}} f(x) = 0, $$
we might define a function $\overline{f} : [3,\infty)$ by the formula
$$ \overline{f}(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=3$, and} \\
f(x) & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
Then $\overline{f}$ agrees with $f$ on all of $(3,\infty)$, $\overline{f}$ is continuous on its domain $[3,\infty)$, and $\overline{f}$ has a root at $x=3$.  It is possible that this is what WolframAlpha is doing.

More generally, we could work with the (principle) complex logarithm, which will have two roots (at $x=3$ and $x=-3$).  This, however, requires some complex analysis to make rigorous.